# Деление и работа с числами высокой точности.

Tags: c++

1. Как при делении двоих чисел вывести
      40 знаков после точки?
2. Возможно ли эти 40 знаков
      сохранять в переменной?

Comment: Проще всего реализовать деление в столбик...

Comment: Ну че так сразу? может человек решил число пи высчитать ^^

Comment: дада =))))

Comment: число Пи - иррациональное, а значит его нельзя представить в виде частного от деления двух чисел

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Формально вот так:

```
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(40) << 1.5
```

Но проблема в том, что это не имеет смысла, т.к. double, а уж тем более float, не хранит числа с такой высокой точностью.

Например в типе double под хранение мантиссы отведено 52 бита. 2^52 равно около 4*10^15, поэтому максимальное число десятичных знаков, которое может хранить double, по этим грубым прикидкам, не превосходит 16.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите например (первая в Google по c++ biginteger):

https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/

Answer (score 1):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
int a=171, b=37, i, r;

printf("\n%.17lf", (double) a/b);
printf("\n%d,", a/b);

r = a;

for ( i=0; i < 40; i++) {
    r = (r-b*(r/b)) * 10;
    printf("%d", r/b);
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Очень интересно, только **можно ли верить этим разрядам ? **

Кстати, объясните такой результат Вашей программы:

    int a=1171, b=377, i, r;
     
    3.10610079575596830
    3,1061007957559681697612732095490716180371

Видите, последние 2 разряда (ну, с одним бы я еще согласился) при делении с плавающей точкой уже не совпадают с вычисленными в Вашей итерации.

Comment: у кого есть под рукой математика, маслаб и т.п., могут проверить в них. если нет - идем например на вольфрам и вводим там "=1171/377"
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%3D1171%2F377
верить надо, потому что алгоритм правильный

Comment: собствено алгоритм простой - представление числа a в виде деления с остатком: a = b*n + r. n идет следующей цифрой в представлении числа, а остаток r раскладывается по тому же принципу

Comment: Т.е. результаты не совпадают с правильным алгоритмом из-за ошибок Intel (x86 процессор) ? 

Или gcc криво компилирует **правильную программу** ?

Comment: частное от деления двух чисел - это математический конструкт. в виде формулы a\b он отображается идеально, а  виде цифр - с некоторым приближением. процессор не ошибается, просто его предел приближения ограничен

Comment: Согласен, ошибка в 

    printf("\n%.17lf", (double) a/b);

Действительно, при операциях с double можно доверять **только 16** десятичным разрядам (17-й округление) и неважно, сколько после десятичной точки задано в спецификации формата.

Это мой последний комментарий здесь (Лимит-с).
А Вам ++.

Comment: спасибо. собственно формат %.17 я и написал, чтобы показать максимум, на который способна double-переменная. при больших размерах printf будет писать только нули